# Google Play Games ClientConnectionOperation: Handling ConnectionFailedException

Tags: android, google-play-games, game-profile

Does anyone else experience those problems, every since google launched the [game profile](http://officialandroid.blogspot.co.il/2016/02/embrace-your-inner-gaming-hero-with.html). I am getting problems with connecting to play services.

Here what I get when running [google sign in flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

```
ClientConnectionOperation: Handling ConnectionFailedException
com.google.android.gms.drive.api.a.r: Unable to resolve account name.
    at com.google.android.gms.drive.api.a.q.a(:com.google.android.gms:71)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.service.f.run(:com.google.android.gms:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.a.c.run(:com.google.android.gms:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Comment: Which part of the google sign-in flow did you start encountering this?

Comment: I have the same problem. I wish someone had an answer for this.